# Adjusting AVAudioMix volume property has no effect in iOS9

Tags: avplayer, ios9

I have an app which loads local files into an avPlayer via a AVMutableComposition, it may have as many as 6 audio and video tracks as part of the composition.

I have a UISlider which is used to adjust the volume of each track in the player.

Below is the code used to update the volume.

```
- (void)updateVolumeForTake:(Take *)take
{    
    NSInteger trackID = // method that gets trackID

    AVMutableAudioMix *audioMix = self.player.currentItem.audioMix.mutableCopy;
    NSMutableArray *inputParameters = audioMix.inputParameters.mutableCopy;

    AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters *audioInputParams = [inputParameters filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:kTrackIdPredicate, trackID]].firstObject;

   [audioInputParams setVolume:myNewVolumeFloat atTime:myDesiredTime];

    audioMix.inputParameters = inputParameters;

    AVPlayerItem *playerItem = self.player.currentItem;
    playerItem.audioMix = audioMix;
}
```

This is is currently live in the appStore and has been since iOS6 and has always worked with no issue.
On a device running iOS9, the above no longer works at all. I have looked at the release notes and although there is some mention of AVFoundation, I didn't see anything regarding AVAudioMix.I have googled around and have not found anyone else with this issue.

I also tried creating a new project with nothing but an AVPlayer and UISlider and I saw the same behaviour.

My question is as follows, has anyone else experienced this issue? 
Is anyone aware of a known bug related to this?

Answer (score 5):

I have found a solution but unfortunately not an exact cause.

I can't say I fully understand why this fixed my issue but here is the solution and an attempt at explaining why it fixed the issue I was experiencing.

```
- (void)updateVolumeForTake:(Take *)take
{

    AVMutableAudioMix *audioMix = [AVMutableAudioMix audioMix];
    NSMutableArray *inputParameters = [self.inputParameters filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:kNotTrackIdPredicate, myTrackID]].mutableCopy;

    AVCompositionTrack *track = (AVCompositionTrack *)[self.composition trackWithTrackID:myTrackID];
    AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters *audioInputParams = [AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters audioMixInputParametersWithTrack:track];
    [audioInputParams setVolume:myDesiredVolume atTime:kCMTimeZero];

    [inputParameters addObject:audioInputParams];
    audioMix.inputParameters = inputParameters;

    AVPlayerItem *playerItem = self.player.currentItem;
    playerItem.audioMix = audioMix;

    self.inputParameters = inputParameters;
}
```

As you can see above, I have stopped using mutable copies of my AVAudioMix and its inputParameters and instead created a new AVAudioMix and NSMutableArray for inputParameters. The new inputParameters array is a copy of the existing inputParameters (referenced from a property 'self.inputParameters') minus the track matching the one I wish to change.

Secondly I create a new instance of AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters using the track with which I wish to edit the volume of (previously I was getting reference to the existing params with matching trackID and modifying them). I edit that add it to my new array and make that the audio mix of currentItem.

Again I can't say with any certainty why this fixes it, but it did for me, I wonder if all the mutable copies were not being discovered as different at all when I reassigned the audioMix of the playerItem and thats why I didn't hear any change in the volume. (although this seems doubtful).

Anyway my issue is fixed and I hope this can help anyone who has a similar issue.

Comment: Thank you so much! Exactly what fixed my problem 5 years later :)

Comment: Actually all you have to do is two things:
1. Create a copy of the inputParams and reassign to the `inputParameters` property on `AVMutableAudioMix`
2. Re-assign `audioMix` property on the player item.
You don't need to create new `AVMutableAudioMix`
The point is that when you just update a value in the inputParameters the `AVMutableAudioMix` doesn't get notified about that in any way. SO you just need to set updated values back to `inputParameters ` so that it takes them into account.